# Can't connect to remote MySQL using scala, play, slick

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

just downloaded the [play-scala-slick-silhouette](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fsbrunk%2Fplay-silhouette-slick-seed&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHmUy-0meoZBlntMs2U35GBVpsKDQ) template and tried to change from h2 to my MySQL.

Everything works fine when connecting to a local MySQL server, but it fails with the following error, when I try to connect to my remote MySQL instance.
java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1004ms of waiting for a connection.

Double checked credentials, url, port etc. Same db settings work fine in another project.

```
slick.dbs {
    default {
        driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$",
        db {
            driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
            url = "jdbc:mysql://urlt:port/dbName",
            user = "userName",
            password = "password"
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1- Check that your mysql driver matches the version of your mysql server.
2- Check the firewall on your remote server to see if it accepts incoming connections to your mysql port from where you are running your project.
3- Check if your mysql deamon is configured to accept connections from remote clients.

Comment: I have a second project (another slick template from typesafe) which is set up with the same MySQL driver, running on the same machine and connecting to the same MySQL instance with the same credentials.

I have a similar issue here: just the first attempt after starting the app fails, but the second+ runs through.

But in this project here, it fails always...

Comment: This is weird. Are you connecting to the same database in both applications?

Comment: Jopps, same db, same user, etc. All db setup is exactly the same...
Weird indeed. :-D

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with slick play evolution plugin. Connection to DB failed even if connection timeout set to 30 seconds. Everything works fine if plugin disabled. I found two workarounds:

1. Disable connection pool by adding `slick.dbs.default.db.connectionPool = disabled` to config. (don't recommend to use this approach)
2. Adding connection test query to config - `slick.dbs.default.db.connectionTestQuery="select version();"`

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Play 2.4 and Slick 3.1.1 (play-slick 1.1.1), if I disable the evolutions, everything works properly but in presence of evolutions, it fails with a timeout. I'm going to try your second workaround, but I'd really like to know what's happening (I looked into all mailing list discussions in Play and Slick but no one gave a clear explanation/solution).